# MsAccess select similar addresses

Tags: ms-access

I have Ms Access query something like:

```
SELECT [tbl1].[StreetAd] FROM tbl1
GROUP BY [tbl1].[StreetAd]
HAVING (((Count(tbl1.Sort))>1
```

It'll select same street addresses and unique Sorts.
I need the same thing but - to select SIMILAR addresses -
if the first 4 address characters match.

when I do:

```
SELECT [tbl1].[StreetAd] FROM tbl1
GROUP BY Left([tbl1].[StreetAd], 4)
HAVING (((Count(tbl1.Sort))>1
```

Access shows mistake.

What's wrong & how to write correct query?
Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Left([tbl1].[StreetAd], 4)
FROM tbl1
GROUP BY Left([tbl1].[StreetAd], 4)
HAVING Count(tbl1.Sort)>1
```

then to get the full addresses you can join the previous query with `tbl1`:

```
SELECT Distinct [tbl1].[StreetAd]
FROM
  tbl1 INNER JOIN
  (SELECT Left([tbl1].[StreetAd], 4) as Left_Addr
  FROM tbl1
  GROUP BY Left([tbl1].[StreetAd], 4)
  HAVING Count(tbl1.Sort)>1) tbl1_b
  ON Left([tbl1].[StreetAd], 4) = tbl1_b.Left_Addr
```